# Adding a BG image using Tailwind CSS - Module Not Found error

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am attempting to add a background image to a component in a next.js app that I am building. The structure of the app is similar to their sample blog project as I am using that to build off. When I attempt to view the page locally I get a 404 error when it attempts to locate the image.

Currently, my tailwind (v. 3.2.6) config file contains this codeblock:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'header-image': "url('/public/images/Desktop-Banner.png')",
      }
    },
  },
```

The implementation in a component looks like this (see line 3), this component is added to the _app.js file with no further modification (Please ignore the amateur use of the Link component):

```
export default function Header() {
    return(
        <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-4 bg-header-image" >
            <div className="col-span-3"></div>
            <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-3">
                <div>
                    <Link href={`/`} className="text-blue-500 text-xl text-center">Home</Link>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Link href={`../about`} className="text-blue-500 text-xl text-center">About</Link>
                </div>
                <div>Vacancies</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the file structure looks like this:

[File Structure of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB8Zv.png)

When I attempt to run the project, the background image (but not the rest of the component/SPA) fails to load and the following message appears in the console:

[Error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VANxA.png)

---

Here are the solutions I have attempted:

1. Changing the URL link to:
   `'header-image': "url('./public/images/Desktop-Banner.png')",`
   or,
   `'header-image': "url('/images/Desktop-Banner.png')",`
   These cause the entire SPA to fail loading with a "Module failed to load" error.
2. Removing the definition from the tailwind config and using an [arbitrary value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values), this also fails for the reason above.
3. Removing the bg-header-image from the component itself and adding it directly to _app.js instead. This fails for the above reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. The solution was to:

1. Create a src folder in the root.
2. Add the image there and update the links in tailwind-config.

Solution link: [Here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3113)

Answer (score 0):

Adding what worked for me for anyone else struggling with the same problem. To quote the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets):

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. **Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/)**.

So for the example provided in the question you would remove `/public` in order to change `'header-image': url()` to the following:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'header-image': "url('/images/Desktop-Banner.png')",
      }
    },
  },
```

I even took out the single quotes (`'`) within `url()` to be `'header-image': "url(/images/Desktop-Banner.png)"` and it still worked for me.